# Android Google Map get correct location not work

Tags: android, google-maps

I am try to write sample code to test Google maps API in my application. Everything looks good, but when I open Google maps from my app it stops working.

Please give me some help.

```
public class SmarttreenearbyActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_smarttreenearby);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    double y = location.getLatitude();
    double x = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(x,y);

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [FusedLocationApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi). It's an official Google API that allows us to get the location without creating complex location logic by ourselves.

Comment: Um.. I would Like to know what is happen for my code :) but still thank you.

Comment: I used GoogleMaps on some apps I developed. I strongly recommend you follow @TheSunny recomendation. Go with this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location?hl=pt-br